# How to transform a multipartite state in tensor form into a bipartite state?

Tags: quantum-state, linear-algebra

I have a 5-party state represented as a tensor of dimensions (2,2,2,2,2). We want to transform it to a bipartite state such that the parties 3 and 4 are on one side and parties 1,2,5 are on the other.

If it was a density matrix, it could be accomplished by tracing out. Is it possible to do this in a tensor product form by just reshaping the tensors? I think that to get parties 1,2 on one side and 3,4,5 on the other, we could just reshape the tensor as (4,8). Would that be correct? But I don't know how I would reshape to get parties 3 and 4 on one side and 1,2,5 on the other

Comment: Can you give your concrete example here?

Comment: @narip For example, if it was the generalized GHZ state 1/√2 (|00000⟩+|11111⟩). How would a bipartition of parties 3 and 4 one side and 1,2,5 on other be achieved?

Comment: It's [entangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenberger%E2%80%93Horne%E2%80%93Zeilinger_state#:~:text=certain%20type%20of-,entangled%20quantum%20state,-that%20involves%20at), it cannot be written as $|...\rangle\otimes |...\rangle$ form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your supposition is entirely correct: We just have to reshape the original $5$-qubit state, which is a rank-$5$ $2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2$ tensor, into a rank-$2$ $4 \times 8$ tensor. To accomplish this, generally speaking, we have to permute the indices in such a way that a given set of qubits (which, for the concrete example you suggested, would be qubits $(3,4)$) lie on one side of the bipartition and the remaining qubits (in this case, $(1,2,5)$) lie on the other, and then we just reshape the rank-$5$ tensor into a rank-$2$ tensor of appropriate dimensionality.

On Python, we can make use of built-in NumPy functions to perform these two steps effortlessly. Suppose we are given some $32$-dimensional vector $\texttt{psi}$, which represents a $5$-qubit state. We first reshape it into a rank-$5$ tensor: $\texttt{psi = np.reshape(psi, (2,2,2,2,2))}$. Then, we reorder the $2$-dimensional indices (i.e., we place the third and fourth qubits, $(2,3)$, on the left-hand-side, and the first, second, and fifth qubits, $(0,1,4)$, on the right-hand-side) according to the bipartition we are given: $\texttt{psi = np.transpose(psi,(2,3,0,1,4))}$. Finally, we apply the bipartition: $\texttt{psi = np.reshape(psi, (4,8))}$.

For clarity, all code lines are shown together below, including a first line that simply generates a random $5$-qubit state using a Qiskit function.

```
import qiskit, numpy as np

psi = qiskit.quantum_info.random_unitary(32).data[:,0]
psi = np.reshape(psi, (2,2,2,2,2))
psi = np.transpose(psi, (2,3,0,1,4))
psi = np.reshape(psi, (4,8))

print(psi)
print(psi.shape)
```